# Will a Firestore SnapshotListener attached to a field-based Query be triggered for newly inserted documents with this field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The question isn't very clear sorry. I couldn't formulate it better. I have attached a Firestore SnapshotListener on the following query:

```
Query getListOfSlots(String uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("list_of_slots").whereEqualTo("owner", uid);
}
```

Then I have added a new document that contains a value for `owner`, using this CollectionReference:

```
CollectionReference getListOfSlots() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("list_of_slots");
}
```

What I want to know is:

- Does my newly created document trigger the SnapshotListener? I think yes, since I have specified a value of the field `owner` because the SnapshotListener listens on a Query which selects documents according to this field `owner`.

Edit: the answer seems to be "no". Waiting for confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a modified version of [this example snippet](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/71642c5f40145a91c4199549fdd169175930dccf/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L799-L825) from the [Cloud Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), you should be able to see each changed document if it applies to the query being listened to:

```java
db.collection("list_of_slots")
  .whereEqualTo("owner", uid)
  .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                          @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
          if (e != null) {
              Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
              return;
          }

          for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
              switch (dc.getType()) {
                  case ADDED:
                      Log.d(TAG, "New slot: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                      break;
                  case MODIFIED:
                      Log.d(TAG, "Modified slot: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                      break;
                  case REMOVED:
                      Log.d(TAG, "Removed slot: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                      break;
              }
          }

      }
  });
```